# publishing .rds file in reporting server using rss script

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I am having several rdl files which uses the shared data source, which is defined in the sample.rds file. Now when i try to publish the .rdl files using the rss scipt, i am getting the below error,

> ```
> The dataset `Sample' refers to the shared data source `Sample', which is not published  on the report server.  The shared data source `Sample' must be published before this report can run.
> ```

It clearly says the 'Sample' data source referred in rdl files is not published.

So before trying to publish the rdl files, i need to publish the sample.rds file. How to do that? How do i publish the .rds files using the rss script?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to BIDS?
If yes, you can just open your project, right click it and deploy.

All datasources will be deployed to the folder specified on the project configuration

Answer (score 0):

Creating it manually worked for me:

1. Browse to `http://localhost/Reports_SQL2008`
2. Click New Data Source, add `Name="Sample", connectionstring="Data Source=.\sql2008; Initial Catalog=yourDB;"`
3. Use Windows credentials
4. Save